# Java not insalled after "sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jre / sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk"

Tags: apt, package-management, java, openjdk, jdk

I am getting the follwoing error message:

```
Command 'java' not found, but can be installed with:

sudo apt install default-jre              # version 2:1.11-72, or
sudo apt install openjdk-11-jre-headless  # version 11.0.15+10-0ubuntu0.20.04.1
sudo apt install openjdk-13-jre-headless  # version 13.0.7+5-0ubuntu1~20.04
sudo apt install openjdk-16-jre-headless  # version 16.0.1+9-1~20.04
sudo apt install openjdk-17-jre-headless  # version 17.0.3+7-0ubuntu0.20.04.1
sudo apt install openjdk-8-jre-headless   # version 8u312-b07-0ubuntu1~20.04
```

How do i install it correctly?

Comment: I am missing the question ...

Comment: can you add the command that you used to install Java? also can you add the contents of your path variable (echo $PATH)?

Comment: $ echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-17-oracle/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-17-oracle/db/bin

Comment: $ echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-17-oracle/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-17-oracle/db/bin